# limit partial collection from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was trying to limit the rendering of partial collection, but I **cannot change the controller or model** (don't ask why, it's hard to explaint). So I have to **limit it in view** and only solution I could come up with is this

```
def suggested
   @suggested ||= current_user.suggested_friends
end

<%= render :partial => 'layouts/three_panel_widgets/friend', :collection => suggested[0..3] %>
```

do you have any better ideas ?

Comment: looks like you already have best solution for your situation, if you cant change code of controller/model.

Comment: you could move the [0..3] or limit(4) to the helper as well, which will make the view look even better.  Quite acceptable to use a helper for this.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using rails 3, you can use `suggested.limit(4)`. It will generate a SQL with LIMIT clause. This is a little bit better then using `suggested[0..3]`.

```
<%= render :partial => 'layouts/three_panel_widgets/friend', :collection => suggested.limit(3) %>
```

Comment: thx for answer, but the "suggested" collection is relly complex collection of arel and direct in code SQL and .collection(&:object)